# How to use source (not presenting) in animationController (UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate)?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm making a custom Transition Manager. It conforms to the protocols `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` & `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`.

When `present`ing from `RocketsVC` to `RocketDetailsVC`, func is called `animationController(for Presented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController)`, the following types are passed there:

- `presented`: `RocketDetailsViewController`
- `presenting`: `MainTabBarController` (Error is here)
- `source`: `RocketsViewController`

This functions are declared in `TransitionManager.swift`:

```
func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    type = .presentation
    return self // TransitionManager
}
```

And then `animateTransition` method is called...

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    guard let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) as? TransitionManagerProtocol,
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) as? TransitionManagerProtocol
```

...with zero effect, because `MainTabBarController` does not conform to `TransitionManagerProtocol`.

If I build a project without `MainTabBarController` (rootVC is RocketsVC), then everything works as it should.

**What should I do to make the transition work?** I'm sinning on `MainTabBarController`, but maybe there is a way to somehow pass to `animationController` method `source` instead of `presenting`?

[Full code is in my GitHub](https://github.com/htmlprogrammist/SpaceX/tree/rockets-transition-3-so)

[TransitionManager.swift](https://github.com/htmlprogrammist/SpaceX/blob/rockets-transition-3-so/SpaceX/Services/TransitionManager.swift)
[RocketsViewController.swift](https://github.com/htmlprogrammist/SpaceX/blob/rockets-transition-3-so/SpaceX/Controllers/Rockets/RocketsViewController.swift)
[MainTabBarController.swift](https://github.com/htmlprogrammist/SpaceX/blob/rockets-transition-3-so/SpaceX/Controllers/MainTabBarController.swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've found after long hours:

```swift
private var fromVC: UIViewController?
private var toVC: UIViewController?

...

func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    type = .presentation
    fromVC = source
    toVC = presented
    return self
}

func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    type = .dismissal
    toVC = fromVC // last `fromVC` is now `toVC`
    fromVC = dismissed // and now we set this to fromVC
    return self
}
```

And:

```swift
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    guard let fromViewController = fromVC as? TransitionManagerProtocol,
          let toViewController = toVC as? TransitionManagerProtocol
    else {
        transitionContext.completeTransition(false)
        return
    }
    ...
```